# Creating column based on values of other columns in R

Tags: r, boolean-logic

I am trying to create a new column ($Correct) in a data frame based on values in two other columns ($Condition and $Response).

I realise that there are multiple ways of achieving this (I have since used another method), but I'm interested in the reason why the method below did not work.

```
training_data.df$Correct<- 0

training_data.df$Correct[training_data.df$Condition==2 & training_data.df$Response==1] <- 1

training_data.df$Correct[(training_data.df$Condition==1|3) & training_data.df$Response==2] <- 1
```

This method produces the correct values in the output (the new $Correct column), except for cases where $Condition==2 and $Response==2 (the value '1' prints in the $Correct column rather than '0').

This line of code works correctly on its own, but not in combination with the other (last) line for $Condition==1|3.

Can anyone explain why this occurs?

Comment: Without actually digging into it (sorry) and just throwing ideas out - have you tired using || and && so it doesn't vectorise the operation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
training_data.df$Condition==1|3
```

reads as:

- "(training_data.df$Condition is equal to 1)"

or

- "three".

"(training_data.df$Condition is equal to 1)" can be TRUE or FALSE.

"three" not so much.

Whereas what I think you mean is:
"training_data.df$Condition is equal to (either 1 or 3)".

This would be `(training_data.df$Condition==1 | training_data.df$Condition==3)` or `training_data.df$Condition %in% c(1,3)`.